# Does fortran have first-class function?

Tags: fortran, first-class-functions

In Fortran, we can pass a function name as an argument to a subroutine/function.
Does this mean that fortran has first-class functions?
The answer seems to be no, since it seems that fortran does not support returning functions as the values from other functions, or assigning them to variables.

Answer (score 1):

You answered yourself. No, Fortran does not have first class functions.You cannot easily create another function using your Fortran code. Also, a procedure pointer is not a function itself. You cannot construct a piece of code to execute and save it into a thunk and pass it around.